# Trying to do the how-to-npm practice but no directory found

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

the how-to-npm page can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/workshopper/how-to-npm

[image]

Comment: did you try to clear your `cache` ? it may help by running `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 0):

close the current terminal window and reopen and try again.

Comment: which node version do you have ?

Comment: i tried it is working fine, my node js version is v10.16.3.

Comment: my node.js is 12.14.1 version

Comment: try to downgrade to 10.* and try

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not defined the path of **how-to-open** in **Environment Variables** on the System Properties.

Add **;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm** (path of your how-to-open installed directory)

To the end of your Path variable on the **"User variable"** section of the Environment Variables on the System Properties.

Then reopen cmd prompt and type how-to-openagain.It should work now.Hope it helps.

Comment: the npm one is in the path already, should i add another path for how-to-npm?

Comment: Are you using windows(Which verison?) or Linux?